# Let a, b, c be positive integers, suppose 5 divides $a^2+b^2+c^2$ prove that 5 divides at least one of a,b or c

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let a, b, c be positive integers. suppose 5 divides $a^2+b^2+c^2$. prove that 5 divides at least one of a,b or c. I don't really know how to approach this problem. Is there a uniform way to do this that I am not seeing?

Comment: Wait, does $a^2+b^2=c^2$? it says it in the title but not the body.

Comment: Consider possible remainders of squares when divided by $5$

Answer (score 3):

Modulo $5$, each of $a^2,$ $b^2,$ and $c^2$ must be equivalent to one of $0,$ $1,$ or $-1 \pmod 5.$ (Of course you should show this if you have not already established it.)

There are only a few ways to add three numbers selected from $\{-1,0,1\}$ to get a multiple of $5.$ Are there any ways to do it with just the numbers $\{-1,1\}$?

The condition $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $ is not necessary.

Comment: what exactly does adding the three numbers selected from -1,0,1 to get a multiple of 5 mean?

Comment: It means $p,q,r \in \{-1,0,1\}$ and $p+q+r = 5n$ where $n$ is an integer. Note that $5$ is a multiple of $5$ but so is $0.$

Comment: An example would be $0+0+0=0$: all three terms on the left of the equation are in $\{-1,0,1\}$ and the sum is a multiple of $5.$ Relating this to the original question, it says we set all the numbers $a,b,c$ to multiples of $5,$ so all the squares $a^2,b^2,c^3$ are congruent to $0$ modulo $5,$ and the sum also is congruent to $0$ modulo $5.$

Comment: What this means for the question at hand is that we can use calculations like this to decide whether a sum of numbers is divisible by $5$ just by looking at what the numbers are equivalent to modulo $5$, without having to look at the numbers themselves. For example, $346 \equiv 1\pmod5,$ $7839\equiv -1\pmod5,$ and $85895\equiv0\pmod5$; and since $1 + (-1) + 0 = 0,$ it follows that $346 +7839+85895$ is divisible by $5.$ You don't have to actually add the numbers and divide the sum by $5$ to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=5k \implies 2c^2=5k \implies c= 5h$$

indeed since $(2,5)=1$ we have that $k$ must contain at least one factor $5$.